# Android: Get recent location only, not getLastKnownLocation?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am developing an Android application in which current and precise location is key. After GPS fix is detected, it moves to the next activity.

The problem is that I tested it outdoors and found that sometimes it just uses a location from a previous fix.

So what I am asking; is there any other logic to get location from LocationManager other than  by getLastKnownLocation? I haven't yet found an example that wouldn't look something like

```
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sample code from the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) (with little modifications):

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

In here, you just request updates from the GPS, and as soon as the location is received, you'll get a callback call.

Comment: This did it for me! Of course, in my case, I don't have or need location until it _changes_. If I call my next method from 'onLocationChanged' I don't even need to listen for GPS fix. Thanx!

Comment: I did same code..but onLocationChanged() never being called..I dont know what is the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and then call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` passing your own listener implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released new Location API, check this link out https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html,

for you question, you need to implement location update callback to get current location.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: I have tested the new Location API, you don't need to specify the location provider to get location updates anymore. LocationClient will do it for you to get location updates (like in iOS). In new API, you just need to use LocationRequest to set the service parameters like update interval, location accuracy. Then let LocaitonClient to retrieve location updates.